# Is there a way of passing the NDEF message to a string?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, nfc

so I have an NFC tag that stores  a URL and I am building an android app that reads that tag and starts the app to the Main activity.  After that I have a WebView that displays that website. My problem here is, each tag has a different url/path (lets say they are clothing items and each point to a product on the website). How do I get the NDEF message from the tag (the url) and pass it to that parameter of the webview? Thank your for your help, here I will leave my code.

I have followed the android documentation on NFC both, basic and advanced, googled every page and searched everything on reddit, however I could not find any answer...

This is my Main Activity, the one that opens as soon as it reads the tag:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    private var adapter: NfcAdapter? = null

    // Pending intent for NFC intent foreground dispatch.
    // Used to read all NDEF tags while the app is running in the foreground.
    private var nfcPendingIntent: PendingIntent? = null
    // Optional: filter NDEF tags this app receives through the pending intent.
    //private var nfcIntentFilters: Array<IntentFilter>? = null

    private val KEY_LOG_TEXT = "logText"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        initNfcAdapter()
        if (intent != null)
        {
            processIntent(intent)
        }
    }


    private fun initNfcAdapter() {
        val nfcManager = getSystemService(Context.NFC_SERVICE) as NfcManager
        adapter = nfcManager.defaultAdapter
    }


    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        enableNfcForegroundDispatch()
    }

    private fun enableNfcForegroundDispatch() {
        try {
            val intent = Intent(this, javaClass).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
            val nfcPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0)
            adapter?.enableForegroundDispatch(this, nfcPendingIntent, null, null)
        } catch (ex: IllegalStateException) {

        }


    }


    override fun onPause() {
        disableNfcForegroundDispatch()
        super.onPause()
    }

    private fun disableNfcForegroundDispatch() {
        try {
            adapter?.disableForegroundDispatch(this)
        } catch (ex: IllegalStateException) {
        }
    }
    private fun processIntent(checkIntent: Intent) {
        if(checkIntent.action == NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED) {
            val rawMessages = checkIntent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the webview activity:

```kotlin
class Webview : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var webview: Webview1
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview)

        val myWebView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webview)
        myWebView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient () {
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
                if (url != null) {
                    view?.loadUrl(url)
                }
                return true
            }
        }
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://website.com")
        myWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled=true
        myWebView.settings.allowContentAccess=true
        myWebView.settings.domStorageEnabled=true
        myWebView.settings.useWideViewPort=true
        myWebView.settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true)

    }
}
```

I want to pass the NDEF message to myWebVIew.loadUrl().

Comment: Removed my answer, because I'm not your programming service.

Comment: He asked the question in Kotlin, if you reply in Java that's your problem, not his. He asked politely if you could provide the Kotlin solution, not Java. Doesn't make much sense asking a JS question and someone replying in PHP, does it?